# How to improve Java-Blackjack-Counter

Tags: java, loops, counter

I'm trying to make a counter for my blackjack game. The counter should count the ACE'es so it can calculate the points of the Player (Ace is 1 or 11).

It should subtract 10 Points *"setPointsPC(13)"*   if the Player has an ACE and has more than 21 Points. But it should only subtract if it hasn't done it before. If a Player has 2 Ace's it should be like this:

> Player Hit's --> Exceeds 21 --> 10 Points get subtractet --> Player
>   Hit's again --> Exceeds 21 again --> 10 points get subtracted again
>   (now there are no more Ace'es with worth 11) --> Player hits again -->
>   Exceeds 21 --> Player loose the game.

After long work its still not working. It doesn't subtract any points. Here's the code:

```
int acees1 = 0;
if (event.getSource() == bHit) {

        random = getRandom();
        CardsPL1.add(getCard(random));
        setPointsPL(random);

        int counter = 0;
        for(int a = 0; a < CardsPL1.size(); a++){

            if (CardsPL1.get(a).contains("A") && getPointsPL() > 21) { 
                counter++;
                //ACE'es get count here
            }
        }

        if (CardsPC.contains("A") && getPointsPC() > 21 && acees1 < counter){
            setPointsPC(13);
            acees1++;
            //Points get subtracted here if points exceed 21 and acees1 
            //counts how many times it subtracted so it shouldn't do it
            //again if there are more "acees1" than "counter" counted
        }
}
```

Comment: What are `CardsPL1` and `CardsPC`? Why do you have `CardsPL1.get(a).contains("A")` in one place and `CardsPC.contains("A")` in another? Aren't they the same type? And the most important question: did you debug your code?

Comment: Could you paste the code of `setPointsPC`?

Comment: I think `setPointsPC(13);` must be `setPointsPC(getPointsPC()-10)`

Comment: Another question: what does `getRandom()` return? You have `setPointsPL(random);` just before checking `getPointsPL() > 21` so if `getRandom()` doesn't return any value greater than 21 that condition will never be satisfied (assuming the code does what it indicates). Besides that, why do you only count aces if the player has more than 21 points? And why do you count the player's aces but subtract points from pc?

Answer (score 0):

I think you always recalculate points for the set of cards (after takeing new card). My function is as below, where `CharSequence s` represents cards sequence with '2-9' numbered, A=ace, other=face or 10.

```
static public int blackjackPoints(CharSequence s) {
    int sum = 0;
    int aces = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        char c=s.charAt(i);
        if (c >= '2' && c <= '9') sum+=c-'0';
        else if (c=='A') ++aces;
        else sum+=10; //other fig
    }
    if (aces>0) {
        if (sum==0 && aces==2) return 21; //not sure
        sum+=aces;
        while (aces>0 && sum+10<=21) {sum+=10; --aces;}
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You can adapt this to your game.